# Kubernetes - How can I route pod egress traffic based on ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application that currently is deployed multiple times to an Kubernetes cluster because it needs to call different sources based on the URLs that it is called with.  You could call them lanes.  These deployments are well automated by a CI/CD pipeline.

The problem is, most of these lanes are not frequently used, yet they still need to be available.  And we have a lot of applications following this pattern.  I'd love to be able to deploy less pods that can handle the traffic of all lanes and still call the appropriate dependencies.

I know we could 'fix' this problem by incorporating switching logic within the application and passing the lane in a header or something, but that seems like a can of worms and can be problematic in production if that logic isn't necessary there.

I know you can have a single deployment with multiple ingresses.

Is it possible to use the ingress API to accomplish something like this in my kube.yml where I could choose or rewrite **outgoing** urls based on which ingress was called?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/

Is there something in the nginx API that I could use in my kube.yml to accomplish this?
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but networking-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Turing85.  I didn't paste any code, but I was hopeful there was an API that allows my to rewrite or reroute traffic or inform my running application based on the ingress.  The line between programming and networking is a little grey these days with app configuration being able to handle a lot of this.  I'm hopeful the thousands of kubernetes ingress questions and service mesh questions similar to this on stackoverflow will help justify leaving this open for anyone to help me out.  Thank you for the feedback though!  I'll take a look at those other resources as well.

Comment: @darktrek, Is your issue resolved? If Yes, please post the resolution steps you have followed as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.